# How to get property of an object to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Learning from Codecademy. I have to get property of an object to a variable( not property value). This is messing with my brain from an hour.

Here is the code (I messed up a bit to find solution. Please use comments understand it correctly. I am confused to ask) 
SCREENSHOT: http://prntscr.com/bcj94x

```
var james = {
job: "programmer",
married: false
};

// set to the first property name of "james"
var aProperty = james["job"];

// print the value of the first property of "james" 
// using the variable "aProperty"
console.log(james["job"]);
console.log(aProperty);
```

I am getting: this in the console when run the script

```
programmer 
programmer
```

Thanks

Comment: So what do you expect to get?

Comment: Everyone seems fine .What's your problem ? What is your question ?

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi i don't understand how he got "Programmer" when the value is "programmer"

Comment: I need to get property of the object to aProperty. Not the property value.

Comment: You mean you need to get `'job'` to `aProperty`? And then do `console.log(james[aProperty]);` `console.log(aProperty);` and get results `'job'` `'programmer'` correspondingly?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That's what codecademy needs.

Comment: Then just assign `var aProperty = 'job';` and you're done.

Comment: This is what they are instructing: **In line 7, set aProperty to a string of the first property in james (ie. the job property).** Is that how it is done. Don't you think it is too straight? I was thinking there should be some method to do it.

Comment: This may help you: http://prntscr.com/bcj94x , this is the code and instruction screenshot

Comment: Let me know if my solution worked for you

Answer (score 1):

What result did you expect?

Defining your object using with the Javascript Object Notation ([JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for short) results in an object with two properties `job` and `married`.

This object is referenced via the variable `james`. Everytime you are using `james` in your code, you are dealing with the referenced object.

The same goes for `var aProperty = james["job"];`. Everytime, when your variable `aProperty` is used, it refers to the `job` property of the object referenced with `james`.

It is like saying: »From now on, when I say "aProperty", I mean the job-property of `james`«.

Your comment is a bit misleading:

> // set to the first property name of "james"

In this case `job` is the *first* property. Correct would be `set to the property named job`.

---

From the above should the result be not unexpected.

```
console.log(james["job"]);
console.log(aProperty);
```

Both print `programmer` because `aProperty` is equivalent to `james["job"]` like saying `Thomas` or `the person who wrote this` is referencing to `me` and thus equivalent.

Comment: NO. That is not a miss leading comment. That is the exact comment they put in the code to give me instruction. I need to get 'job' as the result when I call aProperty.

Comment: It is the *first* by accident. If you change the order of job and married, the reference still holds. but it references not the *first* property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the key associated to a given value, you can do this:

```
var james = {
  job: "programmer",
  married: false
};

Object.prototype.getKey = function (value){
  for(var property in this){
     if(this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          if(this[property] === value )
              return property;
          }
     }
};

console.log(james.getKey('programmer'));
```

It will give you "job".

So, using this function, you can simply write:

```
 var aProperty = james.getKey('programmer');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for in` loop to put the `key` values of the `key : value` pairs found in your **james** object inside an array called **aProperty**, and then print out your results in the console.

```
var james = {
job: "programmer",
married: false
};


var aProperty = [];
for (myvar in obj) {
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(myvar)) {
   aProperty.push(myvar);
 }
}

console.log(aProperty[0]);
console.log(aProperty[1]);
```